# Pre-90s book: man disconnecting from a "plugged in" moon colony

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in the late 90s.  It was borrowed from the local library and was quite old then.

It was about a man who had lived in a lunar colony which had pioneered a way of life that allowed the people to be connected. They had ports surgically implanted and could share info and talk to each other remotely and 24/7. It was frowned upon by the Earth dwellers who thought it was dangerous.

He moved back to Earth and had to disconnect.  Most of the book is about his rehab/recovery on Earth and his discovering more about the lunar colony's connectedness.

I was sure the author was Arthur C. Clarke but I just can't find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you remember the cover of the book?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for things you might be able to add to help people recognize this.

Comment: Doesn't sound like Clarke to me.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it might be "The Naked Sun" - Asimov.
The middle of three books often called the Robot series.

Synopsis from Wikipedia:
The book focuses on the unusual traditions, customs, and culture of Solarian society. The planet has a rigidly controlled population of 20,000, and robots outnumber humans ten thousand to one. People are taught from birth to avoid personal contact, and live on huge estates, either alone or with their spouse only. Face-to-face interaction (referred to in the book as "seeing"), and especially impregnating a woman, when replacement of a decedent is necessary, was seen as unavoidable but dirty. Communication is completed instead through holography (referred to in the book as "viewing") where in contrast to "seeing", they are free of modesty, and have no problem if an interlocutor sees the other's naked body. A two-way teleconference allowed the participants to hear and see each other, but in 3D – an idea almost unheard-of at the time of publication, when color television was a novelty.

Baley insists on face to face conversations, traveling in a closed vehicle because of his own agoraphobia, from his life in the enclosed cities of Earth.